# using whereNotIn and subquery in query builder (Laravel 8)

Tags: laravel, query-builder

I would like to make a controller function to search for users by name and display only those name that are not already in a project.

here is the SQL query to display users with name containing 'mmm' who are not already in project id = 2:

```sql
SELECT `firstname`
FROM `user_details`
WHERE (
  `firstname` LIKE "%mmm%" AND `user_id` NOT IN (
    SELECT `member_id` FROM `project_members` WHERE `project_members`.`project_id` = 2)
)
```

and in the query builder (which doesn't work):

```php
$searchResults = DB::table('user_details')
        ->select('user_details.user_id', 'user_details.firstname', 'user_details.lastname', 'user_details.nickname', 'user_details.status')             
        ->whereNotIn('user_details.user_id', DB::table('project_members')
            ->select('member_id')
            ->where('project_id', '=', $request->project_id)
            ->get()
            ->toarray()
        )
        ->where('user_details.firstname', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->searchString.'%')
        ->orWhere('user_details.lastname', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->searchString.'%')
        ->get();
```

Do you know where I did wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I just needed ->pluck('member_id') instead of toarray()

And also, where/orWhere must be grouped.

```
$searchResults = DB::table('user_details')
        ->select('user_details.user_id', 'user_details.firstname', 'user_details.lastname', 'user_details.nickname', 'user_details.status')             
        ->whereNotIn('user_details.user_id', DB::table('project_members')
            ->select('member_id')
            ->where('project_id', '=', $request->project_id)
            ->get()
            ->pluck('member_id')
        )
        ->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('user_details.firstname', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->searchString.'%')
            ->orWhere('user_details.lastname', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->searchString.'%')
            ->orWhere('user_details.nickname', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->searchString.'%');
        })
        ->get();
```